# Weird OSX retina Chrome scrollbar behaviour with box-shadow and relative content

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

When an outer element has box-shadow and some inner element has a relative position the scrollbar on OSX El Capitan Chrome follows the outline of box-shadow. Take a look at the example to better understand this.

Is this a bug with OSX/Chrome or am I doing something wrong?

[image]
http://jsbin.com/jekawikaci/edit?html,css,output

Comment: can't repro on maverick

Comment: @Kaiido Ok, I'm using El Capitan

Comment: use the -webkit-box-shadow in css for chrome and safari

Comment: @Girish Chrome 10+ support regular box-shadow without webkit prefix

Comment: @Girish: In case your comment wasn't meant to be ironic, Chrome hasn't needed the prefix for box-shadow in 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

Can reproduce on Mavericks with Chrome 49. Had the same problem and it took me hours to figure out it was the box-shadow. Firefox, Safari worked fine.